# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "this.con" is null

Tags: eclipse

no encuentro el error en mi código, se supone que debería funcionar pero nada

```
https://github.com/jdvd2431/java.lang.NullPointerException-Cannot-invoke-java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement-String-because.git
```

> Error en la conexion a la base de datosCommunications link failure
>
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: ***no encuentro el error en mi código*** ¿Y el código?

Comment: No hy código, no sabremos nunca dónde está el error

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas! ecomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 0):

Instale la dependencia de base de datos requerida..(pom.xml dentro)

Ejemplo: for mysql;

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.24</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Dado que el foro y la pregunta están en español, la respuesta, debería de ser en el mismo idioma. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [answer].